# Get response headers from aurelia fetch-client

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-fetch-client

I have a method to return file from web api

```
 public static HttpResponseMessage FileAsFileAttachment(byte[] bytes, string filename)
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes) };

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = filename};

        return result;
    }
```

How can i read Content-Disposition header from responce?

```
 this.httpClient.fetch(`/company/get-asic-fee-autocomplete`).then(data=> { console.log(data.headers.get("Content-Disposition "))});
```

this header always null

How get filename and show all headers in aurelia fetch-client???

Comment: in my case console.log(data.headers) looks like
https://gyazo.com/1d32a4e9226bac151102649d607716fa

Comment: I see that there is a space in your code `data.headers.get("Content-Disposition ")`. Try just `data.headers.get("content-disposition")`

Comment: no matter. this value always null. maybe aurelia fetch-client 
does not support some headers.

Comment: if you try to get `content-type` instead of `content-disposition`, does that work?

Comment: yes. content-type work fine.

Comment: Take a look at the network tab of the developer's tool and make sure that the response header `content-disposition` is present. If it is, tell me and I'll try to investigate

Comment: Yes. content-disposition header is exists(in Fiddler)

Comment: Which version of `fetch` are you using, polyfilled or native?  (are you using `import 'fetch'` somewhere?)

Comment: I use  import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-fetch-client";
"aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.0.0-beta.1.2.5",

Comment: This is described in the Fetch API and is NOT an issue with the aurelia-fetch-client. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers
If you have control over the server this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just summing this up whoever next encounters the issue.
As mentioned above if you have CORS enabled, then

> By default, only the 7 CORS-safelisted response headers are exposed, even though I could see content in response header when debugging. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

The Solution: add this code on the server side

```
Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
```

Answer (score -1):

A CORS-safelisted response-header name, given a CORS-exposed header-name list list, is a header name that is one of

`Cache-Control`
`Content-Language`
`Content-Type`
`Expires`
`Last-Modified`
`Pragma`

any other headers are forbidden in aurelia fetch-client

Any value in list that is not a forbidden response-header name.

more info in documentation [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-list)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Thanks